# "eating apple" vs. "eating apples"

Tags: word-usage

Googling "eating **apple** is good for health" gets more than 900 hits.

Googling "eating **apples** is good for health" gets more than 600 hits.

The results seem to convey an implication that "eating apple" and "eating apples" pretty much mean the same thing.

However, Googling "eating **banana** is good for health" gets more than 1000 hits,

while Googling "eating **bananas** is good for health" gets about 4 hits.

There seems to be some difference. If it is, what is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would you like some apple/apples?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56251/would-you-like-some-apple-apples)

Comment: Your google isn't my google.  When I google those phrases, I see a headline "about 1439" results,  but if you start to browse, you only get 20 hits before you you reach the end. Many hits are to forums based in South Asia. I'm not sure that, when you start to filter, that there is a significant effect here.

Comment: @JamesK Thank you. Would you please attach the google link with that filter?

Comment: By filter I just mean manually looking at each of the twenty hits and seeing which ones are properly edited and which ones are casual unchecked forum posts.

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks for your comments. Your link seems to discuss an opposite topic to mine?

Answer (score 1):

"Eating apple is good for health" is wrong. "Eating apples is good for health" is correct. I see this wording showing up in a Google search, but when I look at the first few hits I find they have other grammar errors, too, so these are not good examples.

You can say "eating chocolate is good for health" because "chocolate" is, or I should say can be, an uncountable noun. "Apple" is not. You have to say "an apple" or "two apples" or some such, not just "apple".

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, thank you. Brain slip.